# Icon and text not rendering in widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to render a button and some text on my camera page, but they are not rendering.

The widget I am trying to render is `text` which contains the icon, and the text itself.
Is there a reason this is not rendering?

```
Widget text(context) {
   Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 110.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 0.0),
                        child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.close,
                                    size: 34, color: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Homepage_1()));
                                },
                              ),
                            ]))));
        
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Name Name',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16.0)),
                        Text(
                          'Front End Developer',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]);
}

  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.center_focus_strong,
                size: 39,
                color: Color(0xd),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff33333D),
              onPressed: () async {
                var result = await controller.takePicture();
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewScreen(
                              imagePath: result.path,
                            )));
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

Edit:

```
Widget text(context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 110.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 0.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.close,
                            size: 34, color: Colors.white),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Homepage_1()));
                        },
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, right: 10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Name Name',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16.0)),
                            Text(
                              'Front End Developer',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]))));
  }

  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.center_focus_strong,
                size: 39,
                color: Color(0xd),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff33333D),
              onPressed: () async {
                var result = await controller.takePicture();
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewScreen(
                              imagePath: result.path,
                            )));
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see ```return``` keyword inside your ```text```. If it is not really there, so it should be :D

Comment: Are you saying it should be rendering? If not, what should it look like? @estatico

Comment: I say that currently I do not see the ```return``` statement inside ```text(context)``` function. It means that it returns null, and not ```Align(... )```. Try to add return in front of ```Align``` in the ```text``` function

Comment: Added an edit. Still not rendering. Can you take a look? @estatico

Comment: Okay, now it's better, but I do not see where you call this 
(```text(...)```) function. It is not called inside ```_cameraControlWidget```, so where it should be rendered, if It is not put inside widget tree?